# Powershell - Prepend angle brackets to XML while preserving whitespace

Tags: powershell

I have a string with leading whitespace that needs an angle bracket '<' prepended:

```
$str = "    !-- here is a line"
```

I'm trying to use String replacement to add in an opening angle bracket while preserving the whitespace to get this result:

```
PS > $str    
"    <!--here is a line"
```

**Attempt 1 (tried this with and without escape character):**

```
$str -replace "(\s+)$str", "$1`<$str"
    !--here is a line
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
$strWOW = $str.TrimStart()
$newstr = "<" + $strWOW
Write-Host $newstr
<!--here is a line
$str -Replace "(\s+)$str", "$1$newstr"
    !--here is a line
```

For some reason, -Replace seems to strip out the angle bracket.  What am I missing here?

Comment: What exact result are you expecting? Are you hoping to preserve or remove the leading spaces?

Comment: Sorry, yes here's what I would expect from either one of the two above commands:  `"    <!--here is a line"`  (with leading white-space).